# How to navigate c++ template instantiations in vim?

Tags: c++, templates, vim

I know that vim has a convenient way to navigate to between matching opening and closing parentheses (), brackets[], and braces{}. I happen to write lots of C++ template code, and would like to have a similar ability to navigate between matching angle brackets <>.

```
// I want to jump from this '<'
//         v
enable_if_t<conditional_t<test_v<x>, y, z>::template w<x, y>::value > 42,
            typename a<b, c>::type>
// ... to this '>'                ^
```

Is there a vim command that does this correctly in a context sensitive manner? Specifically, it should understand when `<` is `less than` and when it opens a template argument list, when `>` is `greater than` and when it closes a template argument list, and when `>>` is right shift and when it closes two template argument lists.

Edit: Would be willing to switch to emacs if it can do this.

Comment: Possibly `set matchpairs+=<:>`

Comment: Does this correctly interpret `<`, `>`, and `>>` based on context?

Comment: vim doesn't understand C++ context for any kinds of brackets - that would require a full C++ parser

Comment: How hard could parsing c++ be? A mere compiler can do it.

Comment: I wouldn't call compilers "mere"

Comment: "How hard could parsing c++ be? " - sound of hollow laughter.  If you "happen to write lots of C++ template code" perhaps you should investigate the technology  a bit before writing lots more.

Comment: I am not an expert in C++, but is there even a context where "less than" or "bit shift" is found inside a template type declaration? If not, it's a moot point, as types will always match correctly. (Now if you put a cursor on a "less than", it will mismatch, but that's your fault then.)

Answer (score 3):

You can configure vim to navigate between matching angle brackets only in c++ files by adding the following to your vimrc

```
autocmd FileType cpp setlocal matchpairs+=<:>
```